# Room & Retrofit : List<Object>

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-room, dao

Id'like to save my News in a Room Database. I know how to do it when the data on the Response is List of News but not when it's a NewsList which contains a list of News.

**Here is my code :**
My API Get function :

```
@GET("other/club.json")
suspend fun getListNews(): Response<NewsList>
```

My model :

```
data class NewsList(
@SerializedName(value = "news")
val news: List<News>)

@Entity(tableName = "news_table")
data class News(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
@SerializedName(value = "id")
var id: Int,

@SerializedName(value = "type")
var type: String,

@SerializedName(value = "date")
var date: String,

@SerializedName(value = "title")
var title: String,

@SerializedName(value = "picture")
var picture: String,

@SerializedName(value = "content")
var content: String)
```

My DAO :

```
@Dao
interface NewsDao {

@Insert
fun insert(news: News)

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertAll(news: NewsList)

@Update
fun update(news: News)

@Delete
fun delete(news: News)

@Query("DELETE FROM news_table")
fun deleteAllNews()

@Query("SELECT * FROM news_table")
fun getAllNews(): LiveData<NewsList>
}
```

Response from the API :

```
"news": [
{
"nid": 1,
"type": "one",
 ...
},
{
"nid": 2,
"type": "two",
 ...
}
]
```

And my Database :

```
@Database(
entities = [News::class],
version = 1,
exportSchema = false
)
abstract class NewsDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

//--- DAO ---///
abstract fun newsDao(): NewsDao

companion object{
    @Volatile private var instance: NewsDatabase? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context): NewsDatabase {
        return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
            instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
        }
    }

    private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) =
        Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, NewsDatabase::class.java, "test.db")
            .build()
}
}
```

I heard about TypeConverters, but what is the best way to do it with this example please ?

Comment: Hey I would sincerely suggest you for maintainability, flexibility and readability to not have a single POJO for both network operation and persistence. The simplest will be to have a generic POJO which both network and dao's will convert their own POJOs into.